# Numpy возвращает неправильный результат при возведении отрицательных чисел в нецелую степень

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Помогите найти ошибку в программе. Программа строит график функции
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если n-чётное число, то график будет располагаться в 1 четверти осей кардинат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если n - нечётное, то график функции располагается в 1 и 3 четвертях. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но программа строит в 1 четверти все графики, как с n - чётным, так и нечетным.
Программа:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
 import numpy as np

 x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 5000)
 print ('Введите n')
 n=float(input())
 z=float()
 z=0
 y=float()
 if n > z:
     y=x**(1/n)
 elif n < z:
     y=x**(1/n)
 elif n == z:
     print ('Ошибка, n/0')
 print (y)


 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
 ax.set_title("Графики функции y=x^1/n", fontsize=16)
 ax.set_xlabel("x", fontsize=14)        
 ax.set_ylabel("y", fontsize=14)
 ax.grid(which="major", linewidth=1.2)
 ax.grid(which="minor", linestyle="--", color="black", linewidth=0.5)
 ax.plot(x, y, label="y = {}^1/{}".format(x,n))
 ax.legend()
 ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
 ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
 ax.tick_params(which='major', length=10, width=2)
 ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=5, width=1)
 plt.show()
```

Вот, что строит во всех случая данная программа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Где ошибка??

Comment: Александр, у тебя на этом сайте вопроса, из них у трех почти одинаковые бессмысленные названия. Постарайся давать более осмысленные заголовки своим вопросам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что Numpy, при возведении отрицательных чисел в нецелые степени возвращает `NaN`. Как следствие мы не видим части графика для отрицательных `X`.

Воспроизведение:

```
In [39]: a = np.arange(-4, 4)

In [40]: a
Out[40]: array([-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3])

In [41]: a ** (1/3)
C:\Users\***\Scripts\ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
Out[41]: array([       nan,        nan,        nan,        nan, 0.        , 1.        , 1.25992105, 1.44224957])
```

Решение:

```
In [43]: np.sign(a) * (np.abs(a) ** (1/3))
Out[43]: array([-1.58740105, -1.44224957, -1.25992105, -1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.25992105,  1.44224957])
```

Данное решение можно использовать только для нечетных `n`, для четных надо использовать просто `x ** (1/n)`.

Итоговая функция должна выглядеть так:

```
y = np.sign(x) * (np.abs(x)**(1/n)) if n % 2 else x**(1/n)
```